# Activity not showing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an activity with a linear layout with various items but when i run the app i dont get anything displayed.

Please help :-)

```
<LinearLayout
    mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:id="@+id/TitleBarLayOut"
        android:background="@drawable/titlebar_gradient">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="70px" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/coverArt" android:layout_width="60px" android:layout_height="60px" android:paddingLeft="10px" android:paddingTop="10px"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/playlistTitle" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="30px"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/playlistMember" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="30px"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottomLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="70px" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/playlistDescriptions" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
setContentView(R.layout.playlistview);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();

LinearLayout titlebar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.TitleBarLayOut);

FeaturedButton = new Button(this);
FeaturedButton.setText("Featured");
FeaturedButton.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
int FeaturedButtonWidth = 50;

playButton = new Button( this );
playButton.setText("Play");
playButton.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
int playButtonWidth = 50;

int titleTextWidth = ((screenWidth-playButtonWidth)-FeaturedButtonWidth);
titleText = new TextView(this);
titleText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
titleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
titleText.setTextSize(14);
titleText.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD), Typeface.BOLD);

titlebar.addView(FeaturedButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

titlebar.addView(titleText, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
titleTextWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

titlebar.addView(playButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

CoverArtDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverArt);
PlaylistTitleDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playlistTitle);
PlaylistMemberDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playlistMember);
PlaylistDescriptionsDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playlistDescriptions);
```

Comment: I think layout placement and view placements is not proper , which might be causing this, better approach is to specify layouts in xml. Through code also we should be able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: i cant seem to manage to get this sorted despite removing layout properties in code or int he xml, any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run your project and I think you are missing:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in your main LinearLayout. If you add it, the bottom linear layout with the textviews is displayed.

Anyway the design is not good. Move the buttons to XML and please rethink your layout ;)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, you are a legend, i know its not the prettiest and well layed out but its how it needs to work for me at the moment. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what the problem is with so little information. Are you using Eclipse with the Android plugin?

What do you mean by "i dont get anything displayed"? Does the app run, but you just get a blank view?

Is your activity listed in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sorry for lack of info, I am using Eclipse and when it runs i get the titlebar and two buttons but in the topLayout and bottomLayout nothing is displayed, no background colour or text.

Comment: Also my activity is listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file